# jQuery - function conflicts

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a WordPress theme and I'm using a few jQuery plugins within it. The problem is that some of these plugins are included in other WP plugins, so the js breaks because of naming conflicts.

I was wondering if there is a way to somehow isolate a set of functions or a .js file from the rest of the scripts that are being included in the HTML document.

something like:

```
function wrap(){

  plugin functions...
  plugin functions...

}

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   wrap.pluginfunction()...
   wrap.pluginfunction()...
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to wrap the whole script like this:

```
var someNewNamespace = (function () {
    // Script goes here

    // If you want to expose functions on the namespace:
    var that = {};

    // Declare a new function to expose:
    that.someFunction = function () {
        // ...
    };

    // Expose a function declared previously:
    that.someOtherFunction = someFunctionDeclaredPreviously;

    return that;
}();
```

This will effectively create a new namespace for the script.  The `someNewNamespace` object will have members like `someFunction` etc. after this executes.  Any variables declared within the anonymous outer function, but not exposed via the `that` object will be inaccessible from outside of the script.

Comment: thanks! and how do I access these functions from `jQuery(document).ready(function($){  });` ?

Comment: As `someNewNamespace.someFunction()` etc.  The members you create on the `that` object inside the anonymous function will become members of the `someNewNamespace` object.

Comment: if I have for eg. `$(".menu").superfish();` where do I append `someNewNamespace` ?

Comment: Aha, so they install jQuery plugin functions.  That requires a completely different approach... basically, you will just have to rename all of the functions, unfortunately.  :(

Comment: the problem is when I update these plugins. I have to rename functions all over again :(

Comment: Yeah... unfortunately I am not aware of an elegant solution to this problem.  Maybe others will chime in with more appropriate answers.

Comment: @cdhowie: your code alone doesn't help enough I suppose, but it's a good idea. If you add some code that changes the names of the imported libraries before you load the conflicting library you can still solve the problem. @Alex: is that an option? To load a script that will change the names/namespace of the functions after loading?

Comment: I think so. How would I do that?

Comment: @Alex: since it is likely that some of the code in the plugins references the jQuery namespace directly, you will have to change the name there while you execute the code and change it back after executing.
SO... if you have `jQuery.fn.superfish` that will be defined twice, store it for later usage like this: `jQuery.fn.superfish2 = jQuery.fn.superfish`. Before calling it you can do the reverse to set it back again. Or if you're lucky, you can just call `$('.menu').superfish2()`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a `noConflict()` method so it won't kill other libraries.

Just call `jQuery.noConflict();` after loading the jquery library and you should be set.

Comment: yes, but in my case these are the same libraries loaded twice. I thought `noConflict()` is for jQuery to work with other JS frameworks. I need a way to safely run 2 scripts which have the same functions :)

Comment: @Alex: in that case the only other options I can think of are:
1. using an iframe
2. changing the order of the code so the conflicts don't bother you